# Is it possible to bind a list of complex json objects to a C# object using an ajax GET request?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Test (List<Person> persons)
{
    ...
}
```

Javascript:

```
var person = { Name: "P1", Id: 1 };
var persons = [];
persons.push(person);
persons.push(person);
var json = JSON.stringify(persons);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Test")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: json,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```

I am trying to send a list of person objects to the controller using a GET request. The problem is that the persons list is always null. When I make a POST request everything works fine.

Is it possible to bind a list of complex json objects to a C# object using an ajax GET request?

Comment: what does the json string look like?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by doing this? Passing complex objects with GET parameters like this seems like the wrong way to be doing things - why *not* use a POST?

Comment: I would take a look at the `System.JSON` Library

Comment: also you might want to POST this

Comment: The thing is I don't want to change data, I only want to get data. So I usually use a GET instead of a POST. I thought I am missing something, don't I?

Comment: @Rookian If you're just retrieving data, then why not issue a POST request containing a list of IDs? You don't really need to post entire `Person` objects.

Comment: This is only an example. But you want to send back the whole person object, because you don't want to fetch the whole list again from the database server.

Comment: If you're not changing anything and you're not looking anything up, what *are* you doing? It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AntP My question is about binding a complex object when using an ajax GET request. As it turned out it is not possible to use a GET request for this. So I will use a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to bind a list of complex json objects to a C# object using an ajax GET request?

No, it isn't. Remember that there's a limit in the query string you could send, so having complex objects in a GET request is probably not something you should be doing anyway. The GET verb is normally used for retrieving data from simple things like an ID and a couple of other query string parameters, not by sending complex objects.